# Can you breed for dragons that aren't unlocked?

Tags: dragonvale

I bred a nebula dragon with another galaxy dragon and I got a incubation time of 7hrs. None of the dragons that I have unlocked have a 7hrs incubation time.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can. I did the same thing except with a different galaxy Dragon and I got a blue egg with brown stone shapes. However as soon as you get the egg it transports to storage and I have no idea how to hatch it. Maybe you need to wait for the level to use it.